# Can't get css transition to work

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I've got this button that I want to animate. To achieve this animation, I want to use **`color`** and  **`box-shadow`**.

The problem is, the transition would only work for one, either **`color`** or **`box-shadow`**.

**Please take a look, here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zwp8U/1/).**

```
    -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow; -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s; -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-property: box-shadow; -moz-transition-duration: 0.1s; -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -o-transition-property: box-shadow; -o-transition-duration: 0.1s; -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-property: box-shadow; transition-duration: 0.1s; transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;

    -webkit-transition-property: color; -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s; -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-property: color; -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s; -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -o-transition-property: color; -o-transition-duration: 0.2s; -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-property: color; transition-duration: 0.2s; transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

The reason I am targeting each property separately, is because I want to avoid using **`all`**.

Thanks

Comment: Include the relevant code in your post too.

Comment: @hjpotter92 The code is in JSFiddle. A click away.

Comment: Please go through [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114942/212576) discussion once.

Comment: Actually, [all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-property) [three](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-duration) [properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function) accept multiple value: http://jsfiddle.net/Zwp8U/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the properties all at once, like this:

```
-webkit-transition:
    box-shadow 0.1s ease-in-out,
    color 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:
    box-shadow 0.1s ease-in-out,
    color 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:
    box-shadow 0.1s ease-in-out,
    color: 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition:
    box-shadow 0.1s ease-in-out,
    color: 0.2s ease-in-out;
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zwp8U/1/)